# Django rest framework with Djoser token authentication token response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, token

As i am using a third party package called djoser to handle the token authentication. i want to customise the response. But after trying to change it, the result is not what i wanted. 
I just wanted to get the token value of the token instead of having "auth_token:" in front.

Here is the link to djoser: https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser

Here is my code :

**serializer.py**

```
class TokenCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        required=False, style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid_credentials': constants.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_ERROR,
        'inactive_account': constants.INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TokenCreateSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = None
        self.fields[User.USERNAME_FIELD] = serializers.CharField(
            required=False
        )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        self.user = authenticate(
            username=attrs.get(User.USERNAME_FIELD),
            password=attrs.get('password')
        )

        self._validate_user_exists(self.user)
        self._validate_user_is_active(self.user)
        return attrs

    def _validate_user_exists(self, user):
        if not user:
            self.fail('invalid_credentials')

    def _validate_user_is_active(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            self.fail('inactive_account')
```

**views.py**

```
    class TokenCreateView(utils.ActionViewMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    Use this endpoint to obtain user authentication token.
    """
    serializer_class = settings.SERIALIZERS.token_create
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def _action(self, serializer):
        token = utils.login_user(self.request, serializer.user)
        token_serializer_class = settings.SERIALIZERS.token
        return Response(
            data=token_serializer_class(token).data,
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )
```

**my custom views.py**

```
    class CustomTokenCreateView(utils.ActionViewMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    Use this endpoint to obtain user authentication token.
    """
    serializer_class = TokenCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def _action(self, serializer):
        token = utils.login_user(self.request, serializer.user)
        token_serializer_class = settings.SERIALIZERS.token
        content = {
            'Token': token_serializer_class(token).data,
            'promptmsg': 'You have successfully login',
            'status': '200'
        }
        return Response(
            data=content,
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )
```

**Result from djoser token authentication:**

Success :

```
{
"auth_token": "da57cd11c34cb4332eaa6cc2cac797d0ee95cafb"
}
```

**Result from my edited djoser authentication**

Success:

```
{
    "Token": {
        "auth_token": "da57cd11c34cb4332eaa6cc2cac797d0ee95cafb"
    },
    "promptmsg": "You have successfully login",
    "status": "200"
}
```

**The result i want**

Success:

```
{
    "Token": "da57cd11c34cb4332eaa6cc2cac797d0ee95cafb",
    "promptmsg": "You have successfully login",
    "status": "200"
}
```

Is there a way to remove the auth_token tag ? i do not mind if its auth_token but as long as the format is what it is expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to access the value:

```
content = {
        'Token': token_serializer_class(token).data["auth_token"],
        'promptmsg': 'You have successfully login',
        'status': '200'
    }
```

That way you are not assigning the entire object.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again, how do i retrieve the user first_name and last_name as i also need to put it inside the content field ?

Comment: @JinNiiSama if you have the `user` object just add the `user.first_name` and `user.last_name`. If not, you need to add it in your view. (Also: no trouble =D )

Comment: I know this maybe too much but after trying out to get user first_name and last_name, i keep getting error. As i am still inexperience with the DRF. Is it possible if u can show me how to code it based on my custom view.py for showing user first_name and last_name ?

Comment: I can't right now, but I will try and come back to you later.

Comment: Just quickly, try: `self.request.user.first_name`

Comment: ah, i run into a error from that code. Im going to start a new question just to not flood the comment